# Get value from Wordpress HTML page to PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have Wordpress page with forms that has amount that needs to be paid written in it like this:

```
<div id="ginput_product_price_2_6" class="ginput_product_price_wrapper">
                    <span class="ginput_product_price_label">Price:</span>
                    <input readonly="" class="ginput_product_price gform-text-input-reset" name="input_6.2" id="ginput_base_price_2_6" value="$0.01">
                </div>
```

And I'm using Paysera(payment service, something like Paypal) API to pay that amount. I have paysera's code like this:

```
try {
$self_url = get_self_url();
    $amount = $_GET['input_6.2'];
$request = WebToPay::redirectToPayment([
    'projectid' => #######,
    'sign_password' => '#####################',
    'orderid' => 0,
    'amount' => $amount,
    'currency' => 'EUR',
    'country' => 'LT',
    'accepturl' => $self_url . '/accept.php',
    'cancelurl' => $self_url . '/cancel.php',
    'callbackurl' => $self_url . '/callback.php',
    'test' => 1,
]);
```

Basically I just want to take that price from "input_6.2" div, and put that into "amount" in PHP code so that Paysera's API can read the amount. Problem is I have no idea how to pass "input_6.2" into PHP code. I tried the way it's written in the code, but no dice. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$amount = $_POST['input_6.2'];` or `$amount = $_REQUEST['input_6.2'];` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention two things. I did try those both out, no dice. And I'm using the php code via "<a href="...file.php">, I'm not sure how that impacts that, I probably need to pass those values via <a href> itself somehow?

Comment: What is input context? If you what to pass by POST it ought to be in a form. If you want to pass by GET you can use a link. Give us more info, please.